# Order Axioms: '<' or '$\leq$'?

Tags: real-numbers, axioms

In the axioms given for the real numbers, I see that the order axioms are sometimes given for the '<' relation and sometimes for '$\leq$'. Which is more commonly used these days?

Comment: You should adopt a convention, explicity state it, and use it.

Comment: It doesn't matter. One is always defined in terms of the other, so it makes no difference.